# Allowing users to input a safe subset of HTML

Tags: php, xss, html

I recently posted [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52303/allowing-users-to-input-a-safe-subset-of-html) on Code Review and it was recommended that I ask you guys about it.

Basically, this will be used to allow users to generate formatted content. It gets put inside of HTML tags, so I don't have to worry about an attacker breaking out of an attribute. If that's not clear, here's an example:

```
<div>
Generated content
</div>
```

**Edit:** I'm not inserting the content into an attribute, so escaping quotes isn't a concern. I know I still have to check for bad attributes inside the user-generated content, which is what a large portion of the script is for.

I've established that I'm vulnerable to an attacker posting a malicious link or posting a tracking image, but that's something I'm willing to accept. I don't think you can prevent that without white listing URLs, which would also dramatically reduce the freedom users have. If there is a feasible way to fix this vulnerability, I'd love to hear about it.

I've read the [OWASP XSS cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), and I think I have all of those bases covered.

What do I have to worry about outside of that cheat sheet? Did I miss anything on it? Is my code future-proof? Am I in way over my head? Should I just switch to BBCode or Markup?

[Current code](http://codepad.org/0KYRIimy)

Comment: Why do ou say “I don't have to worry about an attacker breaking out of an attribute”? A `div` wrapper around user-submitted code does not affect the interpretation of attributes in it, and e.g. `onclick=...` would allow simple injection of JavaScript.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I guess I wasn't clear about that. I'll clarify it right now.

Comment: What would happen if I only wrote `</body>`? This should give you an idea of what can go wrong. For the images/link, you can put them in a query and manually check them (before or after allowing for public viewing).

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia `</body>` gets stripped and the post would appear empty

Comment: Why not just have users write in Markdown? It's everywhere nowadays, even this place.

Comment: What holes I can think of: CSS let trolls ruin the layout. ID attribute can conflict with existing ids on the page. Invalid HTML breaking the page and bypassing the filter. Invalid HTML with Unicode magic bypassing the filter. User-generated HTML violating validation and accessibility, which some developers care about them.

Comment: Need any more information adding to my answer?

Comment: @Meredith : Users won’t be able to do anything nasty if you use [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img). I will allow arbitrary xhtml and ᴄꜱꜱ but user agents will prevent any kind of scripting.

Answer (score 14):

You are in a correct path as you go with whitelisting, but implementing it bullet proof is tricky.

I.e. your  links can be fooled to execute JS by just writing:

```
<a href="JAVASCRIPT:xxx">xss</a>
```

Also, especially older browsers may execute JS in img src etc.

I'd recommend you to go with [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), which, besides XSS, also helps you to deal with broken HTML (tag nesting etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but your example doesn't actually work. See: http://codepad.org/PBpovpRF

Comment: Yep stripos (instead of strpos) catches the specific problem there were in the original code. But I think it is a good example how easy it is to miss something which can lead to XSS. That is why a specific library (combined with CSP as pointed out by SilverlightFox) is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

**Summary: Use an HTML sanitizer, but only in combination with a Content Security Policy as there are constantly new ways to bypass filters.**

After your own processing to allow the subset of white-listed HTML tags through, you should pass your content through a HTML sanitizer.

As well as using some sort of HTML sanitiser, it is recommended to implement a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) too on pages with user HTML content. This is a browser implemented mechanism that will stop in-line JavaScript from being executed if the user does manage to insert malicious script. You can set the CSP to allow external `.js` content only (either on your domain or others that you white-list - e.g. Google Hosted Libraries).

These steps will ensure that if a user does enter `javascript:alert('foo');` or whatever as a link, it will not be executed. If you are allowing `img` tags and `a` tags though, these could possibly point to any web address. They could track, but session information will not be able to be sent with them (e.g. `document.cookie`) because of the CSP.

There are always holes found in HTML sanitizers eventually as browsers and the language of the web develop, such as [this one](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/39709/discuss) in old versions of HTML Purifier (<= v4.1.0). This is why I recommend both approaches in combination with each other to ensure gaps in one method won't leave you vulnerable.

Comment: I actually wasn't aware that you could block internal javascript, so thanks for letting me know about it. So you think I should use my solution and HTML purifier together?

Comment: @Meredith: Yes, that was my suggestion. If you cannot do everything in HTML Purifier then you could chain your processing: `Your subset code -> HTML Purifier -> CSP` to make output safe. If any users have browsers don't support CSP then you have already cleaned the output, if there are any vulnerabilities found in HTML Purifier then you have already disabled JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended you try to implement this yourself. If you do decide to go with user-provided HTML you should take a look at OWASP ESAPI for php [here](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/).